# Running script through ssh and evaluate some var/comand inside the host machine

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, scripting

I'm creating a script to migrate some data between servers.

My headache:

( ... )
`ssh -t -i ${KEY} ${USER}@${HOST} "cd /home/${ACCOUNT}/var/${DOMAIN}/ && tar cf - mail/ -P | pv -s $(du -sb mail/ | awk '{print $1}')  | gzip > mail.tar.gz"`

This command returns something like "I can't find mail folder", and I think I know why.

This comand is evaluated before the ssh connection `pv -s $(du -sb mail/ | awk '{print $1}')`, and the mail folder dont exists in the first server. But if I hardcode the current byte size the script will work.

How can I bypass this situation?

I would use `'` but is already being use in  `'{print $1}'`, also tried to create another variable to acomodate something like `'pv -s $(du -sb mail/ | awk \'{print $1}\') '` but still no luck, I've tried so many possibilites with normal and double quotes.

PS: Sorry for my "engrish"

> Offtopic: I would love if someone points me to some good article(or some crucial keyword to search for) to explain/show all the possibilites to declarate, display and evaluate variables, I don't know the right terminology. Like ${var} and $var, what echo does when you use `"` or `'`, and how to escape duplicated quotes, double quotes, concatenation, etc...

---

> Full script example:

```
clear
printf "\n\n"
echo "********************************  INTERWORX --> CPANEL  *************************************"
printf "\n\n"

USER=root
HOST=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
PORT=xxxx
KEY=/var/somewhere
# ----------------
ACCOUNT=myaccount
DOMAIN=example.com

printf " ► ---------------------- [ ${HOST} ]\n"
printf " ►►---------------------- \n"

ssh -t -i ${KEY} ${USER}@${HOST} "cd /home/${ACCOUNT}/var/${DOMAIN}/ && tar cf - mail/ -P | pv -s \$(du -sb mail/ | awk '{print $1}')  | gzip > mail.tar.gz"

printf "\n ►►► ------------ [ mail.tar.gz ]\n\n"

scp -i ${KEY} ${USER}@${HOST}:/home/${ACCOUNT}/var/${DOMAIN}/mail.tar.gz .
                          ( ... )
```

Comment: Escape any `$` that you don't want to expand with ```\```.

Comment: If I excape like this  `ssh-code` plus `pv -s \$(du -sb mail/ | awk '{print $1}')` I get `pv: (stdin):reading error: Is a directory`

Comment: where are ACCOUNT and DOMAIN variables supposed to be resolved?
On the remote host, or locally?

Comment: Locally, but they are working as expected. Works fine with some random byte size `ssh -t -i ${KEY} ${USER}@${HOST} "cd /home/${ACCOUNT}/var/${DOMAIN}/ && tar cf - mail/ -P | pv -s 10000000  | gzip > mail.tar.gz"`

Comment: Is there any way to check which comand was executed on the host machine? Would help debug this :)

Comment: Well, to follow on from @Tagwint, where do you expect `$(du -sb mail/ | awk '{print $1}')` to be evaluated? I suspect what you want is `\$(du -sb mail/ | awk '{print \$1}')`

Comment: I want to be evaluated at the host machine, but `\$`seem to work but then returns `(stdin):reading error: Is a directory`

Comment: I've added the "full" script to the question

Comment: Could you provide output of `ssh -t -i ${KEY} ${USER}@${HOST}  "echo \$SHELL && \$SHELL -version "` ?

Comment: `/bin/bash
GNU bash, version 4.1.2(2)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)
Copyright (C) 2009 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>

This is free software; you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.`  Also the client machine is an ubuntu, only for testing, then I'll change to centos, and will centos>centos connection. Now is ubuntu->centoos

Comment: You should escape `$1` part of awk arguments too:  to `\$1`
@steeldriver provided that in his comment
Your example shows it is still not escaped

Comment: Yup, you're right. Since the `$1` has inside `\$( )`  I expected that $1 was already excaped. Sorry for the pain in a** guys. Feel free to make a answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you mentioned debugging options in your comments,
I think this rather deserves answer like this:

Use `set -x` as the very first command in the sequence

```
ssh -t -i ${KEY} ${USER}@${HOST} "set -x ; cd /home/${ACCO ....."
```

this clearly shows the failure point in your case:

not escaped $1

```
....
    ++ du -sb mail/
    + pv -s 12314 mail/   # <<< awk printed all the line instead of expected just 1st column with size and that ruined the command
    pv: mail/: read failed: Is a directory
...
```

versus escaped

```
....
 ++ du -sb mail/
 + pv -s 12314    # <<< pv gets expected number
      10kiB 0:00:00 [ 184MiB/s] [=======
....
```